# ASP.NET Allow decimal value with comma in EditorFor

Tags: asp.net, validation, decimal

I want to allow user insert values of price like this:

12
   12,34
   12,3
   (number with comma or wihout it and maximum 2 digits after that)

ViewModel class:

```
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$")] 
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "validation-error" })
```

Above code gives me always error:
"Field Price must be a number"
I can write sth like 12.56, but dot is not what I want to do, because in my country comma is appropriate for currencies values.

What I tried so far is:

1) I added DecimalModelBinder class like this :

```
 public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        ModelState modelState = new ModelState {Value = valueResult};
        object actualValue = null;

        try
        {
            actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(valueResult.AttemptedValue,
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            modelState.Errors.Add(e);
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        return actualValue;
    }
```

And in Global.asax i added in Application_Start method those:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
```

It didn't worked!

2) In web.config I tried with different values of global-culture, like:

```
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en" />
```

'auto' value also didn't help in there..

So anything that I found in different sites via google didn't help me :/

Comment: UP ?
DATE 
ANYONE?